# How to access the values from properties file from Groovy script in Mule 3.5

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

As we can access values from properties file using ${}, anywhere inside the mule flow,how can we access these values from a groovy script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Refer the properties file under property placeholder element in xml.
2. Refer the  values from properties file using ${key} at any place in Groovy script.

Answer (score 3):

${} properties get expanded in your xml when starting your application, the solution would be the same than for any other value you want available in the groovy script. I would save it as a flow variable and then retrieve it from Groovy through the message:

```
<flow name="reading-properties">
    <set-variable variableName="myvar" value="${myvar}" />
    <scripting:transformer name="readingProperties">
        <scripting:script engine="groovy">
            myvar = message.getInvocationProperty('myvar')
            ....
         </scripting:script>
    </scripting:transformer> 
</flow>
```

Comment: Actually I found the solution myself and it seems to be working. You can use ${} inside the script and the values from property placeholder are replaced from properties file. Your solution can be a workaround at times.Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your answer so is highlighted?